# Validation XML XSD Fails

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person"
    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="persons">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML File

```
<root>
  <persons>
    <person>
      <name>name1</name>
      <age>1</age>
      <address>abc abc abc1</address>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>name2</name>
      <age>2</age>
      <address>abc abc abc2</address>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>name2</name>
      <age>3</age>
      <address>abc abc abc3</address>
    </person>
  </persons>
</root>
```

Code that validates XML against XSD:

```
 public static String validateXMLwithXSD(String xmlFile, String xsdFile) {
        String result = "SUCCESS";
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            System.out.println("DocumentBuilderFactory: " + factory.getClass().getName());
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            factory.setValidating(true);
            factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            // Specify our own schema - this overrides the schemaLocation in the xml file
            factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", "d:\\person.xsd");
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            builder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            Node rootNode = document.getFirstChild();
            System.out.println("Root node: " + rootNode.getNodeName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            result = "FAILURE:" + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Error ex) {
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            result = "FAILURE:" + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;

    }
```

It throws

```
DocumentBuilderFactory: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'root'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
```

Update: 
After Davis's answer

```
[exec:exec]
DocumentBuilderFactory: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'persons'. One of '{"http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person":persons}' is expected.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)  


error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'persons'. One of '{"http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person":persons}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080173/validation-xml-xsd-fails/4080259#4080259) is correct about the namespace qualification, your XML should look like:

```
<root xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person">
  <persons>
    <person>
      <name>name1</name>
      <age>1</age>
      <address>abc abc abc1</address>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>name2</name>
      <age>2</age>
      <address>abc abc abc2</address>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>name2</name>
      <age>3</age>
      <address>abc abc abc3</address>
    </person>
  </persons>
</root>
```

Even with a correct XML schema, I have seen that error if the parser can not look up the XML schema correctly.  The method you are using is quite old.  If you are using Java SE 5 or later, you can use the following code to perform validation while parsing an XML document:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("person.xsd")); 

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setSchema(schema);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        db.parse(new File("person.xml"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The target namespace for your schema is http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person, but the sample xml isn't in a namespace at all. Probably you want something like:

```
<p:root xmlns:p="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person">
...
</p:root>
```

Comment: Did you add the p: to all the elements? It needs to be everywhere, not just on root. That's what the targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person" means.

Comment: +1, but technically it's a combination of targetNamespace and elementFormDefault="qualified" that requires all the nodes to be namespace qualified.  If elementFormDefault was set to "unqualified" (or unset) only the globally declared elements would need to be prefix qualified (only "root" in this case).

Answer (score 1):

As David says, but you have to add the namespace to all tags.

Either

```
<p:root xmlns:p="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person">
  <p:persons>
    <p:person>
     ...
    </p:person>
  <p:persons>
</p:root>
```

Or

```
<root xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person">
   <persons>
      ...
   </persons>
</root>
```